# cambiar numero de link de whatsapp usando numeros de mi base de datos

Tags: javascript

Hola de antemano gracias a quien pueda ayudarme con un tema que no puedo resolver, estoy armando una pagina web para un proyecto propio, necesito encontrar la manera de poder usar los numeros de telefono de la base de datos y colocarlo en la api de whatsapp

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+ AQUI IRIA EL NUMERO DE MI BASE DEDATOS&text=hola`.

No tengo muchos conocimientos de programacion recien comienzo por ello recurro a ustedes. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste a tu pregunta por favor, revisa [ask] y agrega mayor información a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: HOla Jose, necesitamos mas información, que base de datos estas usando, que lenguajes estas usando como backen, o base de datos frontend, asi es muy dificl ayudarte

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Que base de datos estás ocupando ?
Lo que quieres utilizar es sencillo en tu url deberías ponerle esto:

```
Let num = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' //aquí cargas los # de la base de datos, lo deberías hacer con un for...

Let enlace= `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${num}`

//Aquí puedes presentar el enlace
```

Console.log (enlace)